# Show texts during a loading

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question. I have a loader and during the loading I would show three different texts. Like text1, then this disappear and it's show text2 and then text3.

```
<View style={style.container}>
        <View style={style.page}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#56cbbe" />
          <Text>Text1.. </Text> 
          <Text>Text2.. </Text> 
          <Text>Text3.. </Text>
        </View>
</View>
```

In this case I only show the three texts together. How can I do?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do they all have to display before the loading is complete? Or is this more of a "Things you can read while you wait"? If it's the latter, you could just use some animations to cycle through them without adding any complexity to the component. (EDIT: I made this comment thinking of css animations and react-dom, but hopefully it is still vaguely relevant)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The latter is also ok! At the moment I have the loading and below the three text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use setInterval and call update function to loop through the texts assuming if they are present in form of array.

Simply saying for example.

Let's maintain loadingText in state as `loadingText: ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']`,A variable to track the present item as `currentLoadingTextIndex: 0` and call setInterval in `componentDidUpdate`.
Be careful when calling update function in here,as one wrong mistake will make your app crash.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (!prevState.isLoading && this.state.isLoading) {
      this.timerId = setInterval(this.changeLoadText, 2000);
    } else if (prevState.isLoading && !this.state.isLoading) {
      clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }
  }
```

and finally our update function

```
changeLoadText = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        currentLoadingTextIndex:
          (prevState.currentLoadingTextIndex + 1) %
          prevState.loadingText.length,
      };
    });
  };
```

I am attaching a working expo [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/loop-through-timer-texts) for clarity purpose.

Comment: In this solution I hard coded the values for loadingText as text1,text2,text3 for demo purpose..Rest of the code is generic it will work for any number of text.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to show `indicator` and `text1` during loading time and then `text2` and `text3`. Is that right?

So I made an example for you. This should solve the problem by changing the `status` value. You can display the `indicator` for the duration of loading and show the text by changing the `status` value when loading is complete.

[image: gif]

**Example Code**

```js
//This is an example code to understand ActivityIndicator//

import React from 'react';
//import react in our code.

import { ActivityIndicator, Button, View, StyleSheet,Text } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showIndicator: true };

  componentDidMount() {
     setTimeout(() => {this.setState({showIndicator: false})}, 2000)
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    //function to change the state to true to view activity indicator
    //changing state will re-render the view and indicator will appear
  };

  render() {
    //Check if showIndicator state is true the show indicator if not show button
    if (this.state.showIndicator) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {/*Code to show Activity Indicator*/}
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
                    <Text>Text1.. </Text> 
          {/*Size can be large/ small*/}
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text>Text2.. </Text> 
          <Text>Text3.. </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: "center"
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! And If I would to shows the three text during the loading? So there is the loading and I show first text1, then text2 and then text3, always during the loading?

Comment: If you want to display three text, you can add two text below text1.